# How to update a .jar file inside .ear file and save the .ear file using bash script

Tags: java, linux, bash, shell, zip

How to update a .jar file inside .ear file and save the .ear file using bash script?

The flow works like below:

```
I have an older.ear (located at Documents/older.ear)
that contains older.ear/APP-INF/libs/updateme.jar &
I have a updateme.jar file (located at Documents/libs/updateme.jar), 
which needs to be updated to older.ear/APP-INF/libs/updateme.jar, 
then the ear file has to be saved.
```

As of now, I am been using **7zip**, but would like to have it automated with a bash script.

Answer (score 0):

An `EAR` file is simply a zip file, so you should:

1. Unzip the EAR file by **7z**.
2. Replace the JAR file.
3. Recreate the EAR file by **7z**.

The instructions to accomplish this are trivial, you can write them on your own.

Regards.